# kWh of radioactive elements database?

Tags: energy, reference-request, radioactivity

I recently been studying different radioactive elements. The most difficult part is find the output of these elements in the form of kWh.

Is there a database or chart of these elements' output?

And most importantly does anyone know the kWh of $1~ kg$ of $\ce{^99Tc}$?

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.SE! If you had any questions about the policies of our community, you can ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) or take a ‎‎[tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) of the website‎.

Comment: I don't quite follow the question. kWh is a unit of energy. Are you asking what the total energy released if 1 kg of technetium-99m transitions to technetium-99 emitting mostly gamma rays? (I assume you mean Tc-99m because Tc-99 has an extremely long half-life, but correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: According to Nuclides 2000, the isotopic power of Tc-99 is only 8.6E−06 W/g; the value for Tc-99m is about 4.4E+03 W/g.

Comment: I'm trying to calculate the energy out put of TC 99 like 1 kg uranium 235 puts out 50,000 kWh

Comment: Can you clarify if you are talking about Tc-99 or Tc-99m.

Comment: I am referring to TC-99m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\ce{^{99m}Tc}$ is a nuclear isomer of $\ce{^{99}Tc}$, which is excited by 142.6 keV. Therefore, when one atom decays to $\ce{^{99}Tc}$, it releases 142.6 keV, mostly as gamma radiation, but also some internal conversion occurs. Therefore, for 1 kg of $\ce{^{99m}Tc}$ (10.1 mol):

$$
(142.6\ \mathrm{keV})(10.1\ \mathrm{mol})N_A = 8.673\times 10^{29}\ \mathrm{eV} = 139\ \mathrm{GJ} = 38.6\ \mathrm{MWh}
$$

In general, the total energy released by a nuclear reaction in a given mass is simply the decay energy (commonly known as the Q value) multiplied by the number of atoms. The Q value is simply the difference in mass between the starting material and final product converted to energy:

$$Q = (m_\mathrm{i}-m_\mathrm{f})c^2$$

Q values are easy to just look up, though. ([Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=technetium-99) is a good place)

Of course, depending on the application, all this energy is not accessible or useful. If one were trying to make an [RTG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioisotope_thermoelectric_generator), an enormous amount of shielding would be needed to turn the gamma rays into heat, since they penetrate matter very well, where things like Pu-238 work better because they release mostly alpha particles, which are easily absorbed, delivering their kinetic energy as heat.